# Safari not calculating mixed percentages and pixels in calc() inside border-image-width - any workarounds?

Tags: css, sass, safari, border

I'm implementing a navigation section where the design of two navigation blocks has these arrow icons centered along the top border.

I haven't found a better way to implement this than with border images:

```scss
$arrowWidth: 48px;
$backgroundSidePadding: calc(50% - ($arrowWidth /2));

...

.navigationItemContainer {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-image-slice: 100 0 0 0;
  border-image-width: $arrowWidth $backgroundSidePadding 0 $backgroundSidePadding;
  border-image-outset: calc($arrowWidth / 2) 0 0 0;
...
}
```

The result looks as expected in Chrome and Firefox:
[image: Chrome, Firefox]

However, here's what happens in Safari 14.1.1:
[image: Safari]

What I can see in the *Styles* section in Safari's Dev Tools looks fine:
[image: Styles in Safari]

Yet, in the *Computed* tab, the computed value for `border-image-width` is displayed as `36px 32px 0;`

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? Are workarounds available to make this layout work in Safari?

Comment: Using an absolute positioned pseudo element would be a much more common approach for something like this, I think, than using border-image.

Comment: Thanks! That's what happens when you decide you can implement a design update yourself without involving your usual frontend dev lol.

Comment: Following your tip, I've implemented this using absolute positioned regular elements. This also involved a mixed percent/pixel calc function for `left` and `top`, but in this context, Safari is calculating correctly.

Comment: @CBroe Feel free to post this as a reply for me to accept. Thanks!